# how to insert a variable value into an array key?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have this piece of code:

```
<?php
require_once ('mercadopago.php');

$monto = $_POST['amount'];

$mp = new MP('XXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');

$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
       array(
           "title" => "item",
           "quantity" => 1,
           "currency_id" => "usd",
           "unit_price" => HERE
       )
    )
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference ($preference_data);

?>
```

and I need to make the variable $monto that i define from a post send before to give its value to "Unit_price" where it says "HERE". I tried just writting $monto, but it didnt work.

there is some how i can do this? thanks u and sorry for my english. its not pretty good.

Comment: "unit_price" => $monto  Why you asking again the same question?

Answer (score 2):

you can just use the variable, like:

```
//check if your POST data is not empty and assign some default value in case its empty
$monto = (!empty($_POST['amount'])) ? $_POST['amount'] : 0; //0 is default value
$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
       array(
           "title" => "item",
           "quantity" => 1,
           "currency_id" => "usd",
           "unit_price" => $monto
       )
    )
);
```

Comment: the post data is not empty, and writte just $monto it doesnt work. maybe its because im using smarty templates?

Comment: @user3128221 what do you see when you var_dump($preference_data); ..? and pls clarify your question, as you dont seem to mention anything regarding smarty in your question...!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "title" => "RosquinhaPvP - NickDoPlayer - VIP",
            "quantity" => 1,
            "currency_id" => "BRL",
            "unit_price" => doubleval($monto)
        )
    )
);
```